# Read TFRecord image data with new TensorFlow Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I am having trouble reading TFRecord format image data using the "new" (TensorFlow v1.4) Dataset API. I believe the problem is that I am somehow consuming the whole dataset instead of a single batch when trying to read. I have a working example of doing this using the batch/file-queue API here: https://github.com/gnperdue/TFExperiments/tree/master/conv (well, in the example I am running a classifier, but the code to read the TFRecord images is in the `DataReaders.py` class).

The problem functions are, I believe, these:

```
def parse_mnist_tfrec(tfrecord, features_shape):
    tfrecord_features = tf.parse_single_example(
        tfrecord,
        features={
            'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'targets': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
    )
    features = tf.decode_raw(tfrecord_features['features'], tf.uint8)
    features = tf.reshape(features, features_shape)
    features = tf.cast(features, tf.float32)
    targets = tf.decode_raw(tfrecord_features['targets'], tf.uint8)
    targets = tf.one_hot(indices=targets, depth=10, on_value=1, off_value=0)
    targets = tf.cast(targets, tf.float32)
    return features, targets

class MNISTDataReaderDset:
    def __init__(self, data_reader_dict):
        # doesn't matter here

    def batch_generator(self, num_epochs=1):
        def parse_fn(tfrecord):
            return parse_mnist_tfrec(
                tfrecord, self.name, self.features_shape
            )
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
            self.filenames_list, compression_type=self.compression_type
        )
        dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
        dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
        dataset = dataset.batch(self.batch_size)
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()
        return batch_features, batch_labels
```

Then, in use:

```
        batch_features, batch_labels = \
            data_reader.batch_generator(num_epochs=1)

        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        try:
            # look at 3 batches only
            for _ in range(3):
                labels, feats = sess.run([
                    batch_labels, batch_features
                ])
```

This generates an error like:

```
 [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, Tshape=DT_INT32](DecodeRaw_1, Reshape_1/shape)]]
 Input to reshape is a tensor with 50000 values, but the requested shape has 1
 [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, Tshape=DT_INT32](DecodeRaw_1, Reshape_1/shape)]]
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,28,28,1], [?,10]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have a gist with the full code in the reader example and a link to the TFRecord files (our old, good friend MNIST, in TFRecord form) here:

https://gist.github.com/gnperdue/56092626d611ae23370a21fdeeb2abe8

Thanks!

Edit - I also tried a `flat_map`, e.g.:

```
def batch_generator(self, num_epochs=1):
    """
    TODO - we can use placeholders for the list of file names and
    init with a feed_dict when we call `sess.run` - give this a
    try with one list for training and one for validation
    """
    def parse_fn(tfrecord):
        return parse_mnist_tfrec(
            tfrecord, self.name, self.features_shape
        )
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(self.filenames_list)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(
        lambda filename: (
            tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
                filename, compression_type=self.compression_type
            ).map(parse_fn).batch(self.batch_size)
        )
    )
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()
    return batch_features, batch_labels
```

I also tried using just one file and not a list (in my first way of approaching this above). No matter what, it seems TF always wants to eat the entire file into the `TFRecordDataset` and won't operate on single records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out - the code above is fine. The problem was my script for creating the TFRecords. Basically, I had a block like this

```
def write_tfrecord(reader, start_idx, stop_idx, tfrecord_file):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file)
    tfeat, ttarg = get_binary_data(reader, start_idx, stop_idx)
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(
            feature={
                'features': tf.train.Feature(
                    bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[tfeat])
                ),
                'targets': tf.train.Feature(
                    bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[ttarg])
                )
            }
        )
    )
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

and I needed a block like this instead:

```
def write_tfrecord(reader, start_idx, stop_idx, tfrecord_file):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file)
    for idx in range(start_idx, stop_idx):
        tfeat, ttarg = get_binary_data(reader, idx)
        example = tf.train.Example(
            features=tf.train.Features(
                feature={
                    'features': tf.train.Feature(
                        bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[tfeat])
                    ),
                    'targets': tf.train.Feature(
                        bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[ttarg])
                    )
                }
            )
        )
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

Which is to say - I was basically writing my entire block of data as one giant TFRecord when I needed be making one per example in the data.

It turns out if you do it either way in the old file and batch-queue API everything works - the functions like `tf.train.batch` are auto-magically 'smart' enough to either carve the big block up or concatenate lots of single-example records into a batch depending on what you give it. When I fixed my code that made the TFRecords file, I didn't need to change anything in my old file and batch-queue code and it still consumed the TFRecords file just fine. However, the `Dataset` API is sensitive to this difference. That is why in my code above it always appeared to be consuming the entire file - its because the entire file really was one big TFRecord.